# Django: Redirect logged in users from login page

Tags: django

I want to set up my site so that if a user hits the `/login` page and they are already logged in, it will redirect them to the homepage. If they are not logged in then it will display normally. How can I do this since the login code is built into Django?

Answer (score 84):

I'm assuming you're currently using the built-in login view, with

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

or something similar in your urls.

You can write your own login view that wraps the default one. It will check if the user is already logged in (through `is_authenticated` attribute [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#attributes)) and redirect if he is, and use the default view otherwise.

something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

def custom_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
    else:
        return login(request)
```

and of course change your urls accordingly:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', custom_login),
```

Comment: You should declare `custom_login` with a second argument `**kwargs` so that it passes all arguments you don't care to the built-in `login` view.

Comment: Why isn't this default behaviour? I can't imagine a situation where an already logged in user should see the login page?

Comment: An already logged in user may be redirected to `LOGIN_URL` by `user_passes_test` (and thus `permission_required`) decorators, if he doesn't have enough permissions to access a certain view.

Comment: How to pass the {'template_name': } dict to django's login view if you use it like this?

Comment: You can pass it as `login(request, template_name = 'user/login.html')`

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony seems like LinkedIn doesn't like your logic 

Comment: This doesn't work anymore because `login` has been removed. [@rodolfojcj answer below works.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839973/812919)

Comment: With recent versions of django you can simply use `from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login` instead of `login`. Note that with `redirect_to_login` you must provide a parameter for "next" like so: `redirect_to_login(next='name_of_page_to_redirect_to_after_successful_login')`

Answer (score 68):

## The Django 1.10 way

For Django 1.10, released in August 2016, a new parameter named `redirect_authenticated_user` was added to the `login()` function based view present in `django.contrib.auth` [1].

#### Example

Suppose we have a Django application with a file named `views.py` and another file named `urls.py`. The `urls.py` file will contain some Python code like this:

```
#
# Django 1.10 way
#
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views as app_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', auth_views.login, name='login',
        kwargs={'redirect_authenticated_user': True}),
    url(r'^dashboard/', app_views.Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
]
```

From that file, the relevant part within the `urlpatterns` variable definition is the following, which uses the already mentioned `redirect_authenticated_user` parameter with a `True` value:

```
    url(r'^login/', auth_views.login, name='login',
        kwargs={'redirect_authenticated_user': True}),
```

Take note that the default value of the `redirect_authenticated_user` parameter is `False`.

## The Django 1.11 way

For Django 1.11, released in April 2017, the `LoginView` class based view superseded the `login()` function based view [2], which gives you two options to choose from:

- Use the same *Django 1.10 way* just described before, which is a positive thing because your current code will continue working fine. If you tell Python interpreter to display warnings, by for example running in a console terminal the command `python -Wd manage.py runserver` in your Django project directory and then going with a web browser to your login page, you would see in that same console terminal a warning message like this:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py:54:
>   RemovedInDjango21Warning: The login() view is superseded by the
>   class-based LoginView().

- Use the new `Django 1.11 way`, which will make your code more modern and compatible with future Django releases. With this option, the example given before will now look like the following one:

#### Example

We again suppose that we have a Django application with a file named `views.py` and another file named `urls.py`. The `urls.py` file will contain some Python code like this:

```
#
# Django 1.11 way
#
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views as app_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/',
        auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True),
        name='login'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', app_views.Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
]
```

From that file, the relevant part within the `urlpatterns` variable definition is the following, which again uses the already mentioned `redirect_authenticated_user` parameter with a `True` value, but passing it as an argument to the `as_view` method of the `LoginView` class:

```
    url(r'^login/',
        auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=False),
        name='login'),
```

Take note that here the default value of the `redirect_authenticated_user` parameter is also `False`.

## References

- [1] Relevant section in Django 1.10 release notes at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#django-contrib-auth
- [2] Relevant section in Django 1.11 release notes at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#django-contrib-auth

Comment: @Quique gave a neat solution that works with Django 2.x https://stackoverflow.com/a/53764272/9177173

Comment: I am getting this error when i followed this method. login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'. I got this error when upgraded to Django 2.2. Any reason how to clear it?

Answer (score 27):

For Django 2.x, in your urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
]
```

Comment: This works perfect with Django 2.x. The entire list of auth_urls can be found on github: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py

Comment: How do i do a redirect if i have my url and using django loginview as below. urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='landing.html'), name='landing')
]

Comment: This can also be used for overriding the login view, just above  `path("", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),`

Answer (score 25):

## anonymous_required decorator

### For class based views

**Code:**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def anonymous_required(func):
    def as_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        redirect_to = kwargs.get('next', settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL )
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(redirect_to)
        response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return as_view
```

**Usage:**

```
url(r'^/?$',
   anonymous_required(auth_views.login),
),
url(r'^register/?$',
    anonymous_required(RegistrationView.as_view()),
    name='auth.views.register'
),
# Could be used to decorate the dispatch function of the view instead of the url
```

### For view functions

From http://blog.motane.lu/2010/01/06/django-anonymous_required-decorator/

**Code:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def anonymous_required( view_function, redirect_to = None ):
    return AnonymousRequired( view_function, redirect_to )

class AnonymousRequired( object ):
    def __init__( self, view_function, redirect_to ):
        if redirect_to is None:
            from django.conf import settings
            redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
        self.view_function = view_function
        self.redirect_to = redirect_to

    def __call__( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
        if request.user is not None and request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect( self.redirect_to )
        return self.view_function( request, *args, **kwargs )
```

**Usage:**

```
@anonymous_required
def my_view( request ):
    return render_to_response( 'my-view.html' )
```

Comment: Using a decorator is the best answer.  This type of logic only clutters up the actual views.

Comment: And to add, for CBVs, you're really better off writing it as a mixin and overloading `dispatch()`.  See django-braces for many examples.

Comment: hey, you should be getting more up votes for your answer.  by far the better answer and way more versatile of an approach.

Comment: I am getting this error when i followed this method. login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'. Any reason how to clear it?

Answer (score 12):

Add this decorator above your login view to redirect to /home if a user is already logged in

`@user_passes_test(lambda user: not user.username, login_url='/home', redirect_field_name=None)`

and don't forget to import the decorator

`from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test`

Comment: I love how my suggestion was down-voted w/o an explanation. I'm particularly proud of this discovery because it's elegant, pragmatic, and it's a one liner!

Comment: this is the most elegant solution imo.

Comment: This is great if you are not using the generic views provided by django.contrib.auth

Comment: `user.is_anonymous()` may be better than testing the username.

Comment: I think the downvote may be related to the fact that this function is specifically for redirecting people _to_ the login page.  For example, it encodes the current URL into a `next` GET variable.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation for what's happening here? It's a one-liner, sure, but what is it doing? I'm learning Django and this doesn't quite make sense to me. :(

Answer (score 10):

Since **class based views** (CBVs) is on the rise. This approach will help you redirect to another url when accessing view for non authenticated users only.

In my example the **sign-up** page overriding the [`dispatch()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method.

```
class Signup(CreateView):
    template_name = 'sign-up.html'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('path/to/desired/url')
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views

Add the redirect route in settings

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

And in the URLs add redirect_authenticated_user=True to LoginView

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html',redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login')
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now on. perfect +1

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a pretty old question, but I'll add my technique in case anyone else needs it:

---

**myproject/myapp/views/misc.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as contrib_login, logout as contrib_logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.conf import settings


def login(request, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    else:
        return contrib_login(request, **kwargs)

logout = contrib_logout
```

---

**myproject/myapp/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views.misc',
    url(r'^login/$', 'login', {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'logout', {'template_name': 'myapp/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are done setting up built-in Django user authentication (and using decorators), add this in your settings.py:

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/welcome/'`

NOTE: '/welcome/' here is the URL of the homepage. It is up to you what to replace it with.

Comment: -1, LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is used only when an user successfully logs in

Answer (score -7):

All you have to do is set the "root" url  to the homepage view. Since the homepage view is already restricted for logged on users, it'll automatically redirect anonymous users to the login page.

Kepp the url as it is.
And add something like:

```
(r'^$', 'my_project.my_app.views.homepage'),
```

Comment: Please read the OP carefully. The question is about how to redirect *logged in* users from the login page if they were already authenticated. The built-in `login` view does not cover this case.

Comment: The approach I suggest works just as well. All he wants is for logged in users to skip the login page. My approach suggests that the main (root) page is the home page. Since the home page is login restricted, anonymous users will be redirected to the login page. I've use this approach before. Don't mark my solution down because you don't understand it.

Comment: It still doesn't fix the problem. A logged in user would still be able to reach the the login page (by typing the url or whatever).

Comment: "You don't understand it" LoL – you did not understand the question