# Customized views with django-registration

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-registration

I need to make a very simple modification -- require that certain views only show up when a user is not authenticated -- to django-registration default views. For example, if I am logged in, I don't want users to be able to visit the /register page again.

So, I think the idea here is that I want to subclass the `register` view from django-registration. This is just where I'm not sure how to proceed. Is this the right direction? Should I test the user's authentication status here? Tips and advice welcomed!

**Edit**

I think this is the right track here: [Django: Redirect logged in users from login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page)

**Edit 2**

Solution:

Create another app, for example, `custom_registration`, and write a view like this (mine uses a custom form as well):

```
from registration.views import register
from custom_registration.forms import EduRegistrationForm

def register_test(request, success_url=None,
             form_class=EduRegistrationForm, profile_callback=None,
             template_name='registration/registration_form.html',
             extra_context=None):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return register(request, success_url, form_class, profile_callback, template_name, extra_context)
```

I had to use the same function parameters, but otherwise just include the test, and if we pass it, continue to the main function.

Don't forget to put this in your URLConf either (again, this includes some stuff about my custom form as well):

top-level URLConf

```
(r'^accounts/', include('custom_registration.urls')),
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
```

custom_registration.views

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from custom_registration.views import register_test
from custom_registration.forms import EduRegistrationForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', register_test, {'form_class': EduRegistrationForm}, name='registration.views.register'),
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember django-registration is using function-based views, so you can not really subclass them. The approach I usually follow is "overwriting" the original views (without modifying the django-registration app of course). This works like this:

1. Create another app (you could call it custom_registration or whatever you want)
2. This app need to contain another `urls.py` and in your case another `views.py`
3. Copy the original `register` view code to your new `views.py` and modify it, add a pattern to your `urls.py` to point to this view (use the same url pattern as in django-registration for this view)
4. Put an `include` to your projects `urls.py` of your new app `urls.py` **before** your are including the original django-registration app. This could look like this for example:

> ```
> urlpatterns = patterns('', 
>     ...
>     url(r'^accounts/', include('custom_registration.urls')),
>     url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
>     ... 
> )
> ```

This simply works since the first matching url pattern for `/accounts/register` will point to your new app, so it will never try to call the one from the original app.

Comment: I did most of this already per my edit above, but I'll give it to you. Check out that link and you can see how he wraps a function around the other function, and if you pass the test, you trickle down to the real function. I had to use the same parameters in my test function as found in `register`, but otherwise it works great. No need to duplicate their code beyond that. Check out my second edit for the code.

Comment: Yes, of course, you can also call the original view in your view and returns its response. Actually I do the same all the time. To keep it simple though I dinn't mention that here.

Comment: With the latest and greatest, this answer is now obsolete! Views can be subclassed now.

see [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/) and [django-registration docs](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html)

Comment: Good to know. Will try that out. :)