# Django: Next value is changing oddly in login page

Tags: django, authentication

I wanted to redirect the users in my app to their users page if they were already logged in and tried to go directly to "../login/". I've found this answer:

[Django: Redirect logged in users from login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page)

It works fantastic until I decide to hit the "Registration" link I have below my login fields. I don't know why but when I hit it, I get redirect to the login page again but the only thing that changes is the url, for some reason it becomes "http://localhost:8000/users/login/?next=/users/register/", and it wont take me to my registration page.

Why the "next" variable changes if I've set it with another url in the login template like so:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %}User Login{% endblock %}
    {% block head %}User Login{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
        {% if form.errors %}
            <p>User name or password is incorrect.</p>
        {% endif %}
        <form method="post" action="{% url login %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
                {{ form.username }}</p>
            <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
                {{ form.password }}</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="users/"/>
        </form>
            <li><a href="/users/register/">Register</a></li>
    {% endblock %}
```

I'm using django1.4 and python 2.7. My urls.py are:

For the whole application:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', main_page, name="main_page"),
    url(r'^users/',include('user_manager.urls')),
)
```

For the user_manager module:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('user_manager.views',
    url(r'^$', users, name="user_page"),
    url(r'^logout/$', user_logout, name="logout"),
    url(r'^login/$', user_login, name="login"),
    url(r'^(\w+)/$', user_page),
    url(r'^register/$', register_page),
)
```

Comment: Can you access `http://localhost:8000/users/register/` directly without being logged in?

Comment: @dgel Actually.... no. I didn't realize that until now. But I don't know why either. Anyhow, why do the next token gets the "/users/register" value when I click the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found the problem. Django checks the urls regex in order so the "register" url was matching the "(\w+)/" intended to work for the users pages. So all I had to do is put that url at the end, the urls.py now looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('user_manager.views',
    url(r'^$', users, name="user_page"),
    url(r'^logout/$', user_logout, name="logout"),
    url(r'^login/$', user_login, name="login"),
    url(r'^register/$', register_page),
    url(r'^(\w+)/$', user_page),
)
```

Nevertheless I still don't understand quite well why that mistaken match was changing the next value. I know that caused it but I don't know why...

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `@login_required` decorator on that `register_page` view? If so, remove it