# Django: Within built-in view, how to redirect to / if user already authenticated?

Tags: django, django-1.5, django-login

For the login I usually use the built-in view:

`(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),`

However I noticed today, If I manually go to `myserver.com/login` after an already successful login, I get to see the login page again.

This is not consistent.  One way to solve this, was if I could have these two lines on top of the login view function:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

So that if the user is already authenticated, please redirect to /.

Is there a way to achieve this while still using 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' for login?

**UPDATE:**

It seems someone had this question already: 
[Django: Redirect logged in users from login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page)

However the solution doesn't seem to work any longer in Django 1.5

Within the custom login it throws an exception at:

```
return login(request)
```

-->

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Comment: My personal opinion - don't do it. If the user wants to go the the login page, he should see the login page, no matter if he's logged in already or not.

Comment: https://django-document-korean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/auth.html#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: Redirect logged in users from login page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page)

Comment: The problem was because of a false namespace, hence it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [solution in my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page) works after all.

I had imported the wrong namespace, instead of

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
```

I had imported:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

I hope this helps someone else.