# Django redirect to dashboard after login

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-urls

I created a login page [this is url `127.0.0.1`]. When I sign in, it redirects me to dashboard `127.0.0.1/dashboard` but when I go to `127.0.0.1` I see the login form. I want to create redirect to `127.0.0.1/dashboard` once I'm logged in.

I'm using  Django's authentication system.

Here are my URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'', auth_views.login, name='login'),

]
```

It seems to me that I have to take advantage of the session, but I'm not sure. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Redirect logged in users from login page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Django 1.10 there is a new `redirect_authenticated_user`parameter login view that redirects the authenticated users from viewing the login page. In your urls.py:

```
...
url(r'', auth_views.login, {'redirect_authenticated_user': True}, name='login'),
...
```

By default this parameter is False.