# Django-registration redirect after login ( {{next}} )

Tags: html, django, django-registration

I'm using django-registration to user login in on my website. I need to redirect user to my custom page changing variable {{ next }}. As far as I understand all views and forms are built in, it's unable to custom them. 
I've tried:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'orders'  %}">
```

This code redirects me to this page, using url's name, but django recognized user as not authenticated(not logged in)
Any examples, and advices will be usefull.
Thx.

Comment: post your views.

Comment: maybe because you do not authenticate the user ? Where do you do that ? Can you show that to us ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Redirect logged in users from login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following code in your **settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'your_redirect_url_name'
```

hope it will help you