# How to redirect already authenticated users from login page to home in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to redirect users who are already authenticated to the home page, so they can't access the login page while they are logged in.

This was easily doable for my registration page as its leveraging a function in views.py, but seems to be harder to do for the login page as its leveraging `django.contrib.auth.urls` (so without a function in views.py).

So my question is: how can I redirect users to a specific page **without** going through a view function? In this case, the mydomain.com/login/ page should redirect to mydomain.com when a users is already logged in.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', homepage),
    path('registration/', registration),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Hello @Max you can create decorators to handle authenticated users.

Comment: How would you go about doing that @AnkitTiwari? Because I tried using login_required in the urls.py file, but Django returned an syntax-related error when trying that.

Comment: why you are getting syntax error can you provide it

Comment: provide which error you are getting

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mZJ1ByF

Comment: you have to call decorator on the top of your view function not on urls

Comment: eg.  `@login_required def myview():`

Comment: That's precisely the problem I'm encountering, as I'm not calling the view function here. Anyways, I found a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320581/django-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page/2320702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def myview(request):
    return render(request,'mypage.html')
```

and if you want to redirect user on home page if they are authenticated than do this

create a file named `decorators.py`
inside that create a view which will handle authenticated users

```
def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect('/')
    return wrapper_func
```

it will check that if user is not authenticated it will call function which is passed as parameter else it will redirect user to home page

not you have to import decorators it in your `views.py`

from decorators import unauthenticated_user

and call it on your login function like this

```
@unauthenticated_user
def login(request):
   return render(request,"login.html")
```